# send textbox value to label in another form

Tags: vb.net

i have 4 form : input, form1, form2, form3

input have 3 input : a, b, c
form1 label1 need form1.a
form2 label1 need form1.b
form3 label1 need form1.c

after i click a button in input, form1 show and in several second change to form 2 and that's happen to form2 too, it change to form3, and form3 change into form1. it looping the changing beetwen form

i try this code to send the value

```
Form1.label1.Text = a.Text
Form2.label1.Text = b.Text
Form3.label1.Text = c.Text
```

and i try this code to create the looping beetwen form
in form1

```
form2.show()
me.close
```

in form2

```
form3.show()
me.close
```

in form3

```
form1.show()
me.close
```

the problem is the value sometimes missing and the form not loop like i want anymore
please help

Answer (score 0):

Define `Private MyInput As String = ""` right bellow your class name.

Add this `sub` to all forms

```
    Public Sub ContinueInit(ByVal input as string)
    Me.MyInput = input
    Me.Label1.Text = input
    End Sub
```

Then, in `Button Clicks` add this depends on what form you want to call:

```
form1.show()
form1.ContinueInit(a.text)
me.close

form2.show()
form2.ContinueInit(b.text)
me.close

form3.show()
form3.ContinueInit(c.text)
me.close
```

I hope this helped you to solve your problem. There is an easier way to do it, but this is what I am doing since I got used to this method.

Comment: it says "Error 1 Argument not specified for parameter 'input' of 'Public Sub ContinueInit(input As String)'."

Comment: Oh, read an update. Just delete those `ContinueInit` subs from Form.Load  I have no idea why I added it when you already call that sub from form.show

Comment: Updated once again, you have to define your local variable to connect it to Input parameter.

Comment: what is myinput from me.myinput = input is ? is it my form name that i name input ?

Comment: MyInput is just a declared string in that form, as you can see in the top of my post.